# Google maps controller cannot be initialized, flutter 2.8.1 google_maps_flutter 2.1.1

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

Here i'am asking again on Stack Overflow :), when i try to make a GoogleMapsController variable it show this

```
Non-nullable instance field 'googleMapController' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or a generative constructor that initializes it, or mark it 'late'
```

my controller

```
GoogleMapController googleMapController;
```

[image]

and if i use this

```
Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
```

the Completer is not defined

and if i use

```
late GoogleMapController googleMapController;
```

it will occurs error when i use the controller and say

```
LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'googleMapController' has not been initialized.)
```

i don't understand why people on youtube didn't get any error like this

Comment: The tutorial still using pre-null-safety dart. See https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety for details for your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of null safety your variable must be initialzied when created,

If you are using a Flutter 2.5.3 and later you can use late to tell it that it will be initialized after being created but before being used (that is why people on YouTube didn't get any error like this if they didn't use late ) :

```
  late final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
```

Comment: i already use late and it occurs error when i use the controller said it's not initialized
LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'googleMapController' has not been initialized.)

Comment: i added a new answer and edited the previous one , thanks .

Comment: you know what, i cannot use Completer before because i didn't impot dart:async and no hint in the red undeline code ..... ;'( now it works :D thanks btw

Answer (score 1):

here is the full example for you using same versions flutter 2.8.1 , google_maps_flutter 2.1.1

```
class MapController extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapController({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MapControllerState createState() => _MapControllerState();
}

class _MapControllerState extends State<MapController> {
  late final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  static CameraPosition get _kGooglePlex => const CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  static CameraPosition get _kLake => const CameraPosition(
      bearing: 192.8334901395799,
      target: LatLng(37.43296265331129, -122.08832357078792),
      tilt: 59.440717697143555,
      zoom: 19.151926040649414);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: _goToTheLake,
        label: const Text('To the lake!'),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.directions_boat),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _goToTheLake() async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_kLake));
  }
```

Comment: Just a tiny note: import 'dart:async'; is required for using Completer